# Sorting objects using CSV data

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, sorting, object

Before I start I am noob

So, I made objects using data from a CSV file which was in the form 'doe,john,m,20', which can be seen below:

```
class FitClinic:
    def __init__(self, lname, fname, gender, age):
        self.__lname = lname
        self.__fname = fname
        self.__gender = gender
        self.__age = age

    def __del__(self):
        print("Customer has been deleted")

    def set_lname(self):
        pass

    def get_lname(self):
        return self.__lname

    def set_fname(self):
        pass

    def get_fname(self):
        return self.__fname

    def set_gender(self):
        pass

    def get_gender(self):
        return self.__gender

    def set_age(self):
        pass

    def get_age(self):
        return self.__age

fh=open('fit_clinic_20.csv', 'r')
fh.seek(3)
listofcustomers=[]
for row in fh:
    c = row.split(",")
    listofcustomers.append(FitClinic(c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3:]))
```

What I need to do is sort these objects by the fname attribute which I have no idea how to do, please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sorted` with `key`

```
sorted_list=sorted(listofcustomers,key=lambda x: x.get_fname())
```

Refer to [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org//3.6/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto)

To check the result, you can just print the information with the method you have implemented:

```
for x in sorted_list:
    print(x.get_fname())
```

In a more complicated situation, advised by @Maurice Reeves, you can also add `__str__` and `__repr__` methods.

```
def __str__(self):
    str_to_print=f'lname:{self.__lname},'
    str_to_print+=f'fname:{self.__fname},'
    str_to_print+=f'gender:{self.__gender},'
    str_to_print+=f'age:{self.__age}'
    return str_to_print

__repr__=__str__
```

Then you can print by:

```
for x in sorted_list:
     print(x)
```

Refer to [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__str__#object.__repr__).

BTW, you can use `pandas` to load csv file conveniently.

```
import pandas
csv_pd=pandas.read_csv('fit_clinic_20.csv')
csv_pd.sort_values(by=['fname']) # If fname is the head of your csv file. If not, just add it.
```

Refer to [pandas.DataFrame.sort_values](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas.DataFrame.sort_values)

Comment: Yes, I have tried this method however I get an odd output, something along the lines of: [<__main__.FitClinic object at 0x04029890>, <__main__.FitClinic object at 0x040293D0>, <__main__.FitClinic object at 0x04029210>, <__main__.FitClinic object at 0x040290D0>, <__main__.FitClinic object at 0x04029790>, <__main__.FitClinic object at 0x04029370>, <__main__.FitClinic object at 0x04029410>, <__main__.FitClinic object at 0x04029810>, <__main__.FitClinic object at 0x040291D0>, <__main__.FitClinic object at 0x04029490>, <__main__.FitClinic object at 0x04029150>, <__main__.FitClinic object at 0x04029

Comment: That's right. If you want to get more information, just print each object. `for x in sorted_list: print(x.get_fname())`

Comment: @osmans - you need to implement the str method to get a human readable version of your FitClinic object: https://www.journaldev.com/22460/python-str-repr-functions